# gcc to compile c file that ends with ".C" (Capital C)

Tags: c, gcc

A weird behaviour when I shell:

```
bush@ubuntu:~/CPPWorkspace/Ex12$ gcc users/dubi/justPrnit.C
```

Returns an error:

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

But when I change justPrnit.C to justPrnit.c (with little 'c') it compiled successfully.

What's that?

Comment: Googling `gcc c file capital c` and clicking the first link would have explained it

Comment: googled whole error text but found no answer...

Comment: It's better to google whatever causes the proplem than the actual error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> error trying to exec 'cc1plus'

Because `.C` is assumed to be a C++ source file (`cc1plus` is the C++ parser backend of GCC - by the way, it seems that your local installation of GCC lacks `g++` - are you using the default [incomplete] setup?).

To solve this, use the `-x` switch to force the language:

```
gcc -x c users/dubi/justPrnit.C
```

Answer (score 2):

GCC recognises `.C` as C++, rather than C